# making two spans to the right

Tags: html, css, css-float

I am trying to text align two spans to the right.

```
<span style="float: right;"> close </span>
<span style="float: right;"> x </span>
```

Somehow, x comes before close as follows:

```
 x   close
```

How can I fix it?

Rephrasing the question, I am trying to align two rows to the right like the following:

```
 1,300,000   x
       100   x
```

But all I got is:

```
1,300,000   x
100  x
```

What's missing here?

Comment: There's a lot of different ways you can do it. You can add `display: block` and align text to right if you want two different lines, for example. Or you can use flexbox instead float. There is no need to use floats now that we have flexbox

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I used 'text-align: right' instead of 'float'. Worked. Thanks to all.

Answer (score 1):

You should align it to the right within a parent element:

```
<span style="float: right;">
    <span> close </span>
    <span> x </span>
</span>
```

Comment: Tried this way and it should have worked but it didn't work so I came up with the two floats as above. Anyway, thanks.